# SqlAlchemy Help: Trying to add a child to a child

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this database schema:

```
class Profile_Eval(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'profile_eval'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = Column(String(), unique=True)

    job_descriptions = relationship("Job_Description", back_populates='profile')


    def __init__(self, url=None):
        self.url = url

class Job_Description(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'job_description'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String())
    profile_eval_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('profile_eval.id'))

    profile = relationship("Profile_Eval", back_populates='job_descriptions')

    job_predictions= relationship("Job_Prediction", back_populates='job_description')

    def __init__(self, data=None, profile_eval_id=None):
        self.data = data

class Job_Prediction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'job_prediction'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String())
    score = Column(String())

    job_description_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('job_description.id'))

    job_description = relationship("Job_Description", back_populates="job_predictions")

    def __init__(self, label=None, score=None, job_description_id=None):
        self.label = label
        self.score = score
```

The structure is that each profile has many jobs. Each job has many predictions.

I am able to add a profile like:

`profile = Profile_Eval(url=url)`

and then I am able to add the job descriptions to the profile like:

`profile_record.job_descriptions.append(Job_Description(description))`

but now I'm a little confused as to how I can add the `predictions` to each description.

Should I break it out into their own tables and get rid of the `relationship`? Or is there a way to add them?

Thanks!

Comment: btw, it looks like your __init__ methods are unnecessary. The Base.__init__() method will automatically map keyword arguments to the columns you declared

Comment: @apteryx: op may have written the `__init__` overrides for convenience, so they don't need to use keywords:  eg, `Profile_Eval(url)`

Comment: yea, that's exactly the pattern i was following single

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I break it out into their own tables and get rid of the relationship?

The `Job_Prediction` is already its own table.

> Or is there a way to add them?

yes, add predictions to the descriptions at the same time you're adding the descriptions to the jobs:

```
job_description = Job_Description(description)
job_description.job_predictions.append(...)
#                                      ^^^ whetever you need, here
profile_record.job_descriptions.append(job_description)
```

Comment: oooh, I see what you're doing. Attach the prediction to the description before attaching it to the profile record! Make sense.